# Prove Fibonacci sequence and find partial fraction decomposition

Tags: complex-analysis

We have a function $z/(1-z-z^2)$ which has simple poles at $z=(-1\pm \sqrt5)/2$.

Furthermore we have the powerseries $\frac{z}{1-z-z^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{F_nz^n}$. I have calculated it's radius of convergence to be $(\sqrt5-1)/2$.

We have to prove that $F_0=0, F_1=1, F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}, n\ge2$. (The sequence of Fibonacci numbers). I really need some help on this one, I don't really have any idea how to it!

Next, I have to find the partial fraction decomposition of the rational function. From what I understand, you calculate it like this:$$\frac{r(z)}{q(z)}=\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{l=1}^{m_j}\frac{c_{j,l}}{(z-a_j)^l}$$ where $a_1,...,a_k$ are the zeros of q having multiplicities $m_1,...,m_k$. But then I get $$\frac{z}{1-z-z^2}=\frac{c_1}{z-(\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2})}+\frac{c_2}{z-(\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2})}$$, and I can't seem to calculate it in a way that makes sense.

Comment: Around what value of $\,z\,$ are you developing the power series for the function?

Comment: You should decompose the fraction as $\frac{1}{1-az}+\frac{1}{1-bz}$, so that writing the power series is easy.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, let $f(z) = \dfrac{z}{1-z-z^2}$.

Note that $(1-z-z^2)f(z) = z$. Hence

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_n z^n - \sum_{n=1}^\infty F_{n-1} z^{n} - \sum_{n=2}^\infty F_{n-2} z^{n} = z.$$

Equating powers, you get that $F_0 = 0$, $F_1 - F_0 = 1$ and $F_n - F_{n-1} - F_{n-2} = 0$ for $n \ge 2$.

For the second part, see the hints in the comments.